# Why does this code compile (C++11) without a type mismatch error?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

```
std::vector<char> p = {"abc", "def"};
```

`"abc"` and `"def"` are not `char`, why doesn't the compiler give me an error about this type mismatch?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're not calling `vector`'s constructor that takes an `initializer_list<char>`. That constructor is not viable because, as you said, you're not passing a list of `char`s.

But `vector` also has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes iterators to a range of elements.

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Unfortunately, this constructor matches because the two arguments will each implicitly convert to `char const *`. But your code has undefined behavior because the begin and end iterators being passed to the constructor are not a valid range.